# how to run a C# application on server by client

Tags: c#, server, client

I have a C# application, I want to install it on server then run it on server by client.

I want to it runs on server and I see windows on client and I do my work by client.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

install application on client system and make your database on server it will work

Comment: thanks . how can I config sql connection on Entity Framework code first for client?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a WebService.  Keep in mind, you can't simply "run" code on the server from the client - you can't simply say to a server, "Here's some code - start running it!"  That'd be pretty bad from a security perspective, after all.

How a WebService works is that you program it and deploy it to the server, so that it's code runs on the server.  Then, your client app can connect in to the web service and tell it to run Function XYZ.  Function XYZ is running on the server at that point, and the server will reply back to the client when the request is done.

So your client app is on the user's machine, and able to interact with their windows environment.  Then, when you have something that needs to run on the server, your client app tells your Web Service to go ahead and run.

Comment: I want to run an application on server or other computer like **RemoteApp**